# Wifi not working on Macbook pro mid 2012

Tags: macos, wifi, windows, bootcamp

So it's been 2 months since I use my Mac to install bootcamp, but now there's a problem where I can't even connect to WiFi in windows and now when I go back to os it won't connect WiFi too... All the WiFi drivers on windows have gray color .. Pliss I don't want to reinstall my Mac it's been 2 years and I don't want to lost all my files

Comment: Your questing is a bit unclear, are you saying WiFi does not work booted into Windows **and** macOS? If both are indeed failing you may be looking at a hardware issue.

Comment: Also, reinstalling macOS is possible without loosing data. But having (and updating) a backup regularly is a good idea nevertheless, there is no excuse for loosing data due to lack of backup nowadays.